# Cordova debug/release specific properties

Tags: cordova

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and searched everywhere. It seems it's so obvious that nobody needs to write about it on the web.

However, this is my problem; I'm doing a Cordova application communicating with my REST service. The problem is that I want to use different URL's to my web service depending on, if I'm in debug mode or release mode. Preferably I can even specify my own modes like "dev".

Please help me with options for getting environment/mode specific properties into my app.

Cheers

Martin

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: I have not tested it yet, but this plugin may offer information if the app is built in DEBUG mode or not...

Comment: I've also researched this for a while now and I think the only way is using a plugin: https://github.com/mattlewis92/cordova-plugin-is-debug

Answer (score -1):

While developing application on Cordova I always change URL's manually and the process looked like:

1. Adding new features to the application.
2. Change URL to 'testurl'. Testing features on a test server
3. Pushing feature commits to the main branch
4. Change URL to 'mainurl'. Testing on the main server

Maybe I did not fully understand the question, why you need it to be automatically?

Comment: Manually changing debug/release properties goes wrong from time to time. Sooner or later someone is going to forget. That is my experience anyway. At the moment I'm changing it manually as it is my only option, but I would very much like it automatically so I don't accidentally put test data in my prod environment when it should have been in dev environment.